# mod_rewrite for REST API on PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, mod-rewrite

I want that every call with

```
http://localhost/api/
```

(as **root folder**) for example `http://localhost/api/get/users` actually is `http://localhost/api/index.php?handler=get/users`.

`http://localhost/api/get/user/87` should be `http://localhost/api/index.php?handler=get/user/87` where in **index.php** I would catch $_GET variable **handler** and handle it in proper way.

If I have this kind of rewrite rules it works only for one

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]
```

two

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1&handler2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

three slashes and so on...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1&handler2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?handler=$1&handler2=$2&handler3=$3 [QSA,L]
```

So for the first case `http://localhost/api/a` would work, but `http://localhost/api/a/b` would cause a **Not Found** error.

**EDIT**: Should this be fine?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?handler=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your (own) answer should be fine, just keep in mind that it will redirect **all** incoming URLs to `index.php`. I.e. if you have static files, for example `/js/jquery.js` then it will be changed to `index.php?handler=/js/jquery.js`.

If you want to avoid problems try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: +1 for skipping static files condition. As far as I know the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives have been removed from Apache >= 2.4. Try something like `LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace3` instead.