# getting index.php content in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess

Ok let me explain what problem i am having,

i had create MVC like structure in php to create web API, and using angular as front. now i have create one login page and on button click event `$http.post("user/login")` get executed and in console i am getting output like this.

[image: CONSOLE ERROR]
it is outputting whole index.php content, now i want to know what i am doing wrong?

this is my app.js code.

[image: APPJS]

this is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 p1.html
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ p1.html [L]

Options All -Indexes
```

this is my user.php

```
<?php
class user
{
    public static function login(){
        echo json_encode(array("in user class model"));
    }
}
?>
```

and this is my index.php

[image: index]
i am also using `spl_autoload_register` and `set_include_path`,
need serious help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your request to `/user/login` is rewritten to `/index.php/user/login` due to the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

That's why you just get the response from `index.php`. You'll need your rewrite rule to ignore a specific path that handles your API requests - usually you'd use a common prefix like `/api` for this, for example you could use `/api/user/login`.

For more details on how to achieve this see [the intro to mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

Comment: so how to write my rewrite url?please help

Comment: This answer should also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8642505/1743938